# Kali Linux and Windows

Tags: windows-10, kali-linux

I installed Kali Linux through my USB! It successfully worked! But I cannot boot my windows again and of course I lost all of my data!
I know I can recover the lost data by testdisk but can I boot to normall windows with all the data in the hard disk?

Comment: We will need all the partition info you can get. On which one was Windows installed? On which one is Kali installed now? Did you delete any of the partitions in process of installing Kali? 
Also, which bootloader is used by Kali?

Comment: @doriclazar Bro I followed all these steps to install kali.http://www.kalitutorials.net/2013/11/installing-kali-on-hard-disk-using-usb.html?m=1

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a windows installation DVD? You can run it and start the boot restore tool. Or you can [update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848119/how-to-update-grub-on-a-dual-boot-machine) your GRUB from Kali, it will try to find your windows, if it will fail, you can [add](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB) them manually to grub config file.